# How can I prepopulate the URL address for the add media button

Tags: urls

I was wondering if there is a way to get the URL address to prepopulate with my web address so I don't have to type it in every time I want to insert an image.

Example.

Click on the upload/insert "add media" button --> click "from URL" and instead of having a blank box, I would like it to prepopulate with:

http://mysite.com/images/

this way the only thing I would have to type in is:   nameofimage.jpg

Comment: just wondering... did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a filter to the output of the media insert url form using the filter named `wp_media_insert_url_form`:

```
add_filter('wp_media_insert_url_form', 'ex46632_media_insert_url_form');
function ex46632_media_insert_url_form($html) {
    $html = str_replace('<input id="src" name="src" value=""', '<input id="src" name="src" value="http://mysite.com/images/"', $html);
    return $html;
}
```

Something like this could be added to your theme's `functions.php` file.
**This is untested code that is just as an example of direction.**